# redux - how use nock to test async action

Tags: reactjs, redux, nock

I follow the basic exmaple of redux.org to test async action

action.js

my code is like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function getGoodDataStart(){
    return{
        type: "GOOD_DATA_START"
    }
}
export function getGoodDataSuccess(payload){
    console.log('success', payload)
    return {
        type: "GOOD_DATA_SUCCESS",
        payload: payload
    }
}
export function getGoodDataFail(){
    return{
        type: "GOOD_DATA_FAIL"
    }
}
export function getGoodData(){
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch( getGoodDataStart() )
        return  axios.get('http://www.google.com/list')
            .then( response => {
                console.log('fake res',response)
                dispatch(getGoodDataSuccess (response) )
            })
            .catch( err => {
                console.log('fake err',err)
            })
    }   
}
```

test.js

```
import nock from 'nock'
import React from 'react'
import {expect} from 'chai'
import {getGoodData} from 'registerAction'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const middlewares = [ thunk ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

describe('Register component', () => {

    it('async action', function () {

        nock('http://www.google.com')
        .get('/list')
        .reply(200,'ok!' )

        const store = mockStore({ 
            myData: '' ,
        })
        const expected = [
            {type: "GOOD_DATA_START"},
            {type: "GOOD_DATA_SUCCESS", payload: 'ok!'}
        ]

        return store.dispatch(getGoodData())
            .then( () => { 
                expect(store.getActions()).to.equal(expected)
            })
    })
})
```

The problem I have is, nock is not blocking the request, it lets function getGoodData make real request to google.com. What am I doing wrong?

screen shot of the error:

[image]

Here is the demo: https://github.com/craigcosmo/react-redux-test

install: npm i

to test: npm run test

open url: http://localhost:5051/webpack-dev-server/

Comment: I think it might be because you have a trailing `/` in your `nock` setup. Instead of `nock('http://example.com/')` do `nock('http://example.com')` :)

Comment: removed the `/` and still wouldn't help

Comment: Are you certain you are hitting/nocking the exact same endpoint?

Comment: @MarioTacke I make a demo, updated my question with link to demo

Comment: In your demo app, you are not running tests separately, but through a webpack-dev-server. Is this intentional? Why not run it with `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register`?

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work, so I settled with webpack-dev-server

Comment: You have to fix your import references. I just cloned your project and ran it like above. It works and returns nock data. In particular, you have to fix `registerAction.js` => i from '../constant/actionConstant', and {getGoodData} from '../app/action/registerAction'. Remove the other index.js test file.

Comment: how do you check if it returns nock data?

Comment: You are already logging to console. Look at the return data. It says `"ok!"`

Comment: I don't see that from my end, can you give me a screen shot? And how exactly you run it?

Comment: I update a screenshot of what I saw in the question. Make sure you get the latest code

Comment: It's worth noting here that by using nock in this way your not only testing your own code but you testing axios as well (since axios makes the actual http call).  This deviates from typical unit testing best practices.  I'd recommend not using nock and mocking axios instead, using spies to make sure it was called correctly.  If you're open to that, I'll be happy to provide and example.

Comment: @BenSidelinger yes i'm open to it.

Comment: @angry_kiwi I posted an answer that will show you how to both not have to deal with nock and remove axios from the test by mocking axios and asserting that it was called correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Typically when testing an action like this you'll want to remove anything that is not part of your action from the equation. In this case by simply using nock, you're not removing axios from the equation and are actually adding unnecessary complexity. By mocking axios with a spy, you avoid making the network call and you also avoid calling axios at all.  This allows you to simply assert that axios is called with the correct parameters.  The spy can return a promise that allows testing all the promise handling and subsequent action calls.  In order to demonstrate this, I needed to add a library that provides spies, so I opted to add 'expect' for both assertions and spies, but you could easily do the same thing with sinon if you want to stick with chai.

Here's an example where you don't need nock at all and you just mock axios with a spy:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as registerAction from 'registerAction'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import expect from 'expect'

const middlewares = [ thunk ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

// set up to mock axios methods
import axios from 'axios'
const _get = axios.get

const fakePayload = { foo: 'bar' };
describe('Register component', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        // replace the .get method temporarily with a spy
        axios.get = expect.createSpy().andReturn(Promise.resolve(fakePayload));
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        // restore the get method with our saved const
        axios.get = _get;
    })

    it('async action', function () {
        const store = mockStore({
            myData: '' ,
        })
        const expected = [
            {type: "GOOD_DATA_START"},
            {type: "GOOD_DATA_SUCCESS", payload: fakePayload}
        ]

        return store.dispatch(registerAction.getGoodData())
            .then( () => {
                expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expected)
                expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled()
                expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://www.google.com/list')
            })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

### read https://github.com/node-nock/nock/issues/150

Your tests are doing great on console-

#### add this two script run on your package.json

```
    "itest": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register -R spec  \"test/*.test.js\"",
    "itest:watch": "npm run itest -- --watch"
```

Comment: I added that two commands. I got error when running 'itest'. Error: Cannot find module './options'

Comment: How did you run the tests in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You might need something like this

```
beforeEach(() => {
    nock.disableNetConnect();
});

afterEach(() => {
    nock.cleanAll();
    nock.enableNetConnect();
});
```

[Enable/Disable real HTTP Request](https://github.com/node-nock/nock#enabledisable-real-http-request)

Comment: This solution has same problem, the action is still making real request.

Comment: @angry_kiwi Are you running the application not the tests and expects nock to intercepts it? Nock is only setup to work in tests with this.

Comment: I was running the test